# How can I fix this error with location, adapters and ListView in Android?

Tags: android, listview, android-listview, location, adapter

Hi guys  I have a tricky error that I can't solve. I'm working on a listview and when location services are active I wanna that if location is turned on I watch time to go in a place, and when location services are off I will display a message instead of time. Nothing special. But I have a tricky error like, if I have GPS, so fine location, works, if I have all location turned off, works, but If I have coarse location active, the app crash...this is really tricky. Below my code and my logcat. Thanks guys.

Full class code:

```
package com.example.findmyclients;

import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Collection;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.Comparator;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Iterator;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.ListIterator;

import javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilder;
import javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilderFactory;

import org.w3c.dom.Document;
import org.w3c.dom.NodeList;
import org.w3c.dom.Element;


import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.ListActivity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.location.Location;
import android.location.LocationManager;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuInflater;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.AdapterView.OnItemClickListener;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class ListviewActivity extends Activity{

private ListView lista;
private ListView listaNOGPS;
private List<InterestPoint> listaInteressPoint;
private List<InterestPoint> listaInteressPointNOGPS;
private InterestPoint ip;
private CustomListAdapter adapter;
private CustomListAdapter adapterNOGPS;

public String [][]ArrayTime = new String[1000][6];  //La matrice che conterrà tutti i dati relativi alla lista

public String [][]Dati_history = new String[100][10];
public String [][]Dati_restaurant = new String[100][10];
public String [][]Dati_hotel = new String[100][10];
public String [][]Dati_souvenir = new String[100][10];
public String pathdirectory = "/sdcard/PredappioLiving/";

String[]file_names={"markers_history.xml", "markers_hotel.xml", "markers_restaurant.xml", "markers_souvenir.xml"};
String[]Array_Cat={"Monumenti","Alloggi","Ristoranti","Negozi"};

int nome_luogo = 0;
int categoria = 1;
int auto = 2;
int piedi = 3;
int latitude = 4;
int longitude = 5;

int gps_on= 0;



    @Override
    protected void onCreate (Bundle savedInstanceState){
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_list);

        final Activity thiz = this;

        //Get ListView Object from xml
        lista = (ListView) thiz.findViewById(R.id.lista);
        listaNOGPS = (ListView) thiz.findViewById(R.id.lista);

        GPSTracker gpstrack = new GPSTracker(this);
        if (gpstrack.canGetLocation() ) {
            gps_on = 1;
        }

        /* - - - Costruzione della matrice dall'xml - - - */
        /* - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - -*/
        int file_choice=-1;
        int n = 0;  //mi serve per riempire bene tutta la matrice
        for (int i = 0; i<file_names.length; i++)
        {
            String file_path = pathdirectory+file_names[i];
            int indice_riempimento = n;

            int returnhistory = file_names[i].compareTo("markers_history.xml");
            int returnhotel = file_names[i].compareTo("markers_hotel.xml");
            int returnrestaurant = file_names[i].compareTo("markers_restaurant.xml");
            int returnsouvenir = file_names[i].compareTo("markers_souvenir.xml");

            if (returnhistory == 0){
                file_choice = 0;
            }
            if (returnhotel == 0){
                file_choice = 1;
            }
            if (returnrestaurant == 0){
                file_choice = 2;
            }
            if (returnsouvenir == 0){
                file_choice = 3;
            }

            // Inizio lettura da XML e popolazione della matrice

            try
            {
                DocumentBuilderFactory factory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
                DocumentBuilder builder = factory.newDocumentBuilder();
                Document doc = builder.parse(new FileInputStream(file_path));
                doc.getDocumentElement().normalize();

                NodeList nodi = doc.getElementsByTagName("marker");



                for (int c = 0; c<nodi.getLength(); c++)
                {
                    Element item = (Element) nodi.item(c);
                    String nome = item.getAttribute("name");
                    String destLat = item.getAttribute("lat");
                    String destLong = item.getAttribute("long");

                    Double lat = Double.valueOf(destLat);
                    Double lon = Double.valueOf(destLong);

                    GPSTracker gpsTracker = new GPSTracker(this);

                    String stringMyLatitude = String.valueOf(gpsTracker.latitude);
                    String stringMyLongitude = String.valueOf(gpsTracker.longitude);

                    double currentLat = Double.parseDouble(stringMyLatitude);
                    double currentLong = Double.parseDouble(stringMyLongitude);

                    final float[]distanzadouble = new float[3];
                    Location.distanceBetween(currentLat, currentLong, lat, lon, distanzadouble);

                    float metri = distanzadouble[0];
                    float km = Math.round((double)metri/1000);

                    int minuti_persona = (int)Math.round(metri/125);    //125 metri al minuto -> velocità media di 2,5 m/s
                    int minuti_auto = (int)Math.round(km/0.7);          //700 metri al minuto -> velocità media di 42 km/h 

                    String string_min_a_piedi;
                    String string_min_in_auto;

                    if(minuti_persona <=0)          // Stampa tempo per coprire la distanza
                    {
                        string_min_a_piedi="meno di un minuto";
                    }else
                    {
                        string_min_a_piedi=String.valueOf(minuti_persona);
                    }

                    if(minuti_auto <= 0)
                    {
                        string_min_in_auto="meno di un minuto";                                 
                    }else
                    {
                        string_min_in_auto= String.valueOf(minuti_auto);
                    }

                    ArrayTime[c+n][nome_luogo] = nome;
                    ArrayTime[c+n][categoria] = Array_Cat[file_choice];
                    ArrayTime[c+n][auto] = string_min_in_auto;
                    ArrayTime[c+n][piedi] = string_min_a_piedi;


                }

                n = n+nodi.getLength();


            }catch(Exception e)
            {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }


        }

        //Arrays.sort(ArrayTime, new ColumnComparator(0));




        //Stampa dell'array sulla lista - - -

        /*
        for(int i = 0; i<6; i++)
        {   
            ip = new InterestPoint();
            ip.nome = "pippo"+i;
            ip.categoria ="cat pippo"+i;
            ip.apiedi = "25";
            ip.inauto = "10";
            listaInteressPoint.add(ip);
        }
        */



        final LocationManager manager = (LocationManager) getSystemService( Context.LOCATION_SERVICE );


        if (gps_on == 1) {

            listaInteressPoint = new ArrayList<InterestPoint>();

            for(int i = 0; i<n;i++)
            {
                ip = new InterestPoint();
                ip.nome = ArrayTime[i][nome_luogo];
                ip.categoria = "Categoria: "+ArrayTime[i][categoria];
                ip.inauto = "In auto: " +ArrayTime[i][auto]+ " minuti";
                ip.apiedi = "A piedi: " +ArrayTime[i][piedi]+ " minuti";
                listaInteressPoint.add(ip);
            }

            //Ordinamento
            Collections.sort(listaInteressPoint, new Comparator<InterestPoint>(){

                @Override
                public int compare(InterestPoint elem1, InterestPoint elem2) {

                    return elem1.inauto.compareTo(elem2.inauto);
                }

            });


        }else
        {

            listaInteressPointNOGPS = new ArrayList<InterestPoint>();

            for(int i = 0; i<n;i++)
            {
                ip = new InterestPoint();
                ip.nome = ArrayTime[i][nome_luogo];
                ip.categoria = "Categoria: "+ArrayTime[i][categoria];
                ip.inauto = "In auto:   Attiva la posizione per la distanza";
                ip.apiedi = "A piedi:   in auto e a piedi";
                listaInteressPointNOGPS.add(ip);
            }

            //Ordinamento
            Collections.sort(listaInteressPointNOGPS, new Comparator<InterestPoint>(){

                @Override
                public int compare(InterestPoint elem1, InterestPoint elem2) {

                    return elem1.nome.compareTo(elem2.nome);
                }

            });
        }

       /* 
      //ListView Item Click Listener
            listaNOGPS.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {


                @Override
                public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                        int position, long id) {

                //ListView Clicked item index
                        int itemPosition = position;

                        InterestPoint item = adapter.getItem(position);

                        Intent piu_info = new Intent(thiz, MoreInfoActivity.class); 
                        piu_info.putExtra("nome", item.nome);
                        startActivity(piu_info);
                        //ListView clicked item value
                        //int itemValue = (int) lista.getItemAtPosition(position);

                        //Show Alert
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Position :"+itemPosition+" ListItem :"+ item.nome, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                }
            });

            */  

        //ListView Item Click Listener
        lista.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {


            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                    int position, long id) {

                    if (gps_on == 1){
                        //ListView Clicked item index
                        int itemPosition = position;

                        InterestPoint item = adapter.getItem(position);

                        Intent piu_info = new Intent(thiz, MoreInfoActivity.class); 
                        piu_info.putExtra("nome", item.nome);
                        startActivity(piu_info);
                        //ListView clicked item value
                        //int itemValue = (int) lista.getItemAtPosition(position);

                        //Show Alert
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Position :"+itemPosition+" ListItem :"+ item.nome, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    }else
                    {
                        //ListView Clicked item index
                        int itemPosition = position;

                        InterestPoint item = adapterNOGPS.getItem(position);

                        Intent piu_info = new Intent(thiz, MoreInfoActivity.class); 
                        piu_info.putExtra("nome", item.nome);
                        startActivity(piu_info);
                        //ListView clicked item value
                        //int itemValue = (int) lista.getItemAtPosition(position);

                        //Show Alert
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Position :"+itemPosition+" ListItem :"+ item.nome, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    }


            }
        });

    }

    @Override
        protected void onResume() {
            super.onResume();

            final LocationManager manager = (LocationManager) getSystemService( Context.LOCATION_SERVICE );
            adapter = new CustomListAdapter(getApplicationContext(), R.layout.list_item, listaInteressPoint);
            adapterNOGPS = new CustomListAdapter(getApplicationContext(), R.layout.list_item, listaInteressPointNOGPS);

            if (manager.isProviderEnabled( LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER ) ) {

                lista.setAdapter(adapter);
            }else
            {
                listaNOGPS.setAdapter(adapterNOGPS);
            }
        }
}
```

Logcat:

```
10-28 10:53:53.106: E/AndroidRuntime(445): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
10-28 10:53:53.106: E/AndroidRuntime(445): Process: com.example.findmyclients, PID: 445
10-28 10:53:53.106: E/AndroidRuntime(445): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to resume activity {com.example.findmyclients/com.example.findmyclients.ListviewActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException
10-28 10:53:53.106: E/AndroidRuntime(445):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performResumeActivity(ActivityThread.java:3076)
10-28 10:53:53.106: E/AndroidRuntime(445):  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleResumeActivity(ActivityThread.java:3105)
10-28 10:53:53.106: E/AndroidRuntime(445):  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2476)
10-28 10:53:53.106: E/AndroidRuntime(445):  at android.app.ActivityThread.access$900(ActivityThread.java:175)
10-28 10:53:53.106: E/AndroidRuntime(445):  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1308)
10-28 10:53:53.106: E/AndroidRuntime(445):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
10-28 10:53:53.106: E/AndroidRuntime(445):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:146)
10-28 10:53:53.106: E/AndroidRuntime(445):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5602)
10-28 10:53:53.106: E/AndroidRuntime(445):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
10-28 10:53:53.106: E/AndroidRuntime(445):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
10-28 10:53:53.106: E/AndroidRuntime(445):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1283)
10-28 10:53:53.106: E/AndroidRuntime(445):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1099)
10-28 10:53:53.106: E/AndroidRuntime(445):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
10-28 10:53:53.106: E/AndroidRuntime(445): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
10-28 10:53:53.106: E/AndroidRuntime(445):  at android.widget.ArrayAdapter.getCount(ArrayAdapter.java:330)
10-28 10:53:53.106: E/AndroidRuntime(445):  at android.widget.ListView.setAdapter(ListView.java:486)
10-28 10:53:53.106: E/AndroidRuntime(445):  at com.example.findmyclients.ListviewActivity.onResume(ListviewActivity.java:356)
10-28 10:53:53.106: E/AndroidRuntime(445):  at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnResume(Instrumentation.java:1198)
10-28 10:53:53.106: E/AndroidRuntime(445):  at android.app.Activity.performResume(Activity.java:5530)
10-28 10:53:53.106: E/AndroidRuntime(445):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performResumeActivity(ActivityThread.java:3066)
10-28 10:53:53.106: E/AndroidRuntime(445):  ... 12 more
10-28 10:53:53.161: I/Process(445): Sending signal. PID: 445 SIG: 9
```

**P.S.: With coarse location variable "gps_on" is set to "1" correctly**

Comment: Please remove the "Solved" tag of your title : http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/116101/is-it-ok-to-add-solved-to-the-title-of-a-question.

Comment: Also I see you edit your code to post it corrected. You should not. People with similar problem will come here and with your edit, nobody will understand what the answer is talking about. Please read [ask] to learn more ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

***1.***

```
if (gps_on == 1) {

            listaInteressPoint = new ArrayList<InterestPoint>();  
//rest of the code
} else {  
            listaInteressPointNOGPS = new ArrayList<InterestPoint>();
//rest of the code
}
```

***2.***  ***P.S.: With coarse location variable "gps_on" is set to "1" correctly***

So

***3.***  from your `onResume()`

```
   adapter = new CustomListAdapter(getApplicationContext(), R.layout.list_item, listaInteressPoint);
            adapterNOGPS = new CustomListAdapter(getApplicationContext(), R.layout.list_item, listaInteressPointNOGPS);

            if (manager.isProviderEnabled( LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER ) ) {

                lista.setAdapter(adapter);
            }else
            {
                listaNOGPS.setAdapter(adapterNOGPS);
            }
```

The error you get is for the `getCount()` of a `list` which is initialized but empty, not populated. In this case, `gps_on==1` so `listaInteressPointNOGPS` isn't accessed.

You can change the `if` in `onResume()` and check with an or condition maybe... in the case of coarse location active specifically.

*Important lines from your logcat*:

```
10-28 10:53:53.106: E/AndroidRuntime(445): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
10-28 10:53:53.106: E/AndroidRuntime(445):  at android.widget.ArrayAdapter.getCount(ArrayAdapter.java:330)
10-28 10:53:53.106: E/AndroidRuntime(445):  at android.widget.ListView.setAdapter(ListView.java:486)
10-28 10:53:53.106: E/AndroidRuntime(445):  at com.example.findmyclients.ListviewActivity.onResume(ListviewActivity.java:356)
```

Check which one is line 356 from ListviewActivity.java

Comment: which is line 356 in your class? put it in a try catch and you will know

Comment: I solved with your advice !! thank you, I update my question :D

Comment: great, glad it helped, saved some time :)